# Ansible/Jinja templating

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I am looking to set a fact with its constituent being a dictionary but in below code `my_dict_var`

is rendering as a `string` although I want it to be a dictionary.

```
- set_fact:
    my_fact: "{{ my_fact | default({}) | combine( my_dcit_var ) }}"
  vars:
    my_dcit_var: { "{{ item }}" : ['some string value'] }
  with_items:
    - 1
    - 2
    - 3
```

I am expecting final result should be.
`{1: ['some string value'], 2: ['some string value'], 3: ['some string value']}`
could someone point out my mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The part `{ "{{ item }}" : ['some string value'] }` creates a dict with same key `"{{ item }}"` as a literal string instead of a variable for each item in the loop. So, combine overwrites the dict `key:value` pair with the latest pair every time. Here is how you can fix it,

```yaml
- set_fact:
    my_fact: "{{ my_fact | default({}) | combine( my_dict_var ) }}"
  vars:
    my_dict_var: "{{ { item : ['some string value'] } }}"
  with_items:
    - 1
    - 2
    - 3
```

or, simply

```yaml
- set_fact:
    my_fact: "{{ my_fact | default({}) | combine( { item: ['some string value'] } ) }}"
  with_items:
    - 1
    - 2
    - 3
```

Ansible also recommends use of `loop` instead of `with_` lookup where possible. Here is an example using loop and specified key:value pairs.

```yaml
- set_fact:
    my_fact: "{{ my_fact | default({}) | combine( { item.key: item.val } ) }}"
  loop:
    - { key: 1, val: ['some string value1'] }
    - { key: 2, val: ['some string value2'] }
    - { key: 3, val: ['some string value3'] }
```

Answer (score 0):

The filter [dict](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-items-from-multiple-lists-zip-and-zip-longest) serves the purpose of creating a dictionary from a list of key-value pairs. Let's use filter [product](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#products) to create the list. For example

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        my_fact: "{{ dict(list1|product(list2)) }}"
      vars:
        list1:
          - 1
          - 2
          - 3
        list2:
          - ['some string value']
    - debug:
        var: my_fact
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ my_fact|to_json }}"
```

gives the expected result

```yaml
  my_fact:
    1:
    - some string value
    2:
    - some string value
    3:
    - some string value

  msg: '{"1": ["some string value"], "2": ["some string value"], "3": ["some string value"]}'
```

---

Below is an example of how to use filter [zip](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-items-from-multiple-lists-zip-and-zip-longest) to create a dictionary from two lists. For example

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        my_fact: "{{ dict(list1|zip(list2)) }}"
      vars:
        list1:
          - 1
          - 2
          - 3
        list2:
          - [value-1a, value-1b, value-1c]
          - [value-2a, value-2b, value-2c]
          - [value-3a, value-3b, value-3c]
    - debug:
        var: my_fact
```

gives

```yaml
  my_fact:
    1:
    - value-1a
    - value-1b
    - value-1c
    2:
    - value-2a
    - value-2b
    - value-2c
    3:
    - value-3a
    - value-3b
    - value-3c
```